# Why isn't this Object variable being passed correctly to the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Whenever I click on the `<a>` element, it gives me an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error.

I've been thinking about it, I suspect it might have to do with the variable being an Object, but I haven't managed to figure it out yet.

Here's the frontend code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
                $("#allprod").append("<a href='#' onclick='AddToCart(" + data[i] + ")' class='button expanded success'>Add to cart</a>");
            }
```

And here's the backend AJAX code:

```
function AddToCart(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "./php/cart_add.php",
        data: {
            id: data.id,
            img: data.img,
            name: data.name
        },
        type: "POST"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through the object fine with `Object.keys`, but you cannot access the object with `data[i]`, it should be `data[Object.keys(data)[i]]` - better yet assign the keys to a variable to clean it up a bit.

```
var keys = Object.keys(data);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  // access with data[keys[i]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong with your code.

First, you're attempting to loop through an object's keys the same as you would an array.  While you're somewhat on the right track, you can't simply pass a numeric index to your object unless your keys are actually `0, 1, ..., n`, etc.

Second, it's a lot cleaner to simply attach event listeners to your elements rather than trying to include functions in line.  My code is a bit more verbose than it has to be, but was trying to make it easy to follow.

Third, don't use a period in the URL for your AJAX call, it's likely going to make your request fail.  URLs in web browsers simply use `/` for reference to the root directory (i.e. `/apples.php` is the same as `example.com/apples.php`) or use nothing to reference your present directory (i.e. `apples` when on `example.com/fruits` would send a request to `example.com/fruits/apples`).

Change the first part of your code to:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    $('#allprod').append(
        $('<a href="#" class="button expanded success">Add to cart</a>')
            .click(function() {
                AddToCart(data[key]);
            })
    );
});
```

For your `AddToCart` function, tweak it a bit to this:

```
function AddToCart(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/php/cart_add.php',
        data: data,
    });
}
```